# Handling secrets in Google App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: google-app-engine

If I need to store API keys, passwords, or other sensitive information for a Google App Engine app running in the standard environment to access (let's say in order to access third-party services), what are my best options for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard good things about KMS

https://cloud.google.com/kms/

> Easily Encrypt Secrets
>
> Wrap secrets up to 64KiB in size, to allow you
>   to protect secrets like user credentials and API tokens. Take
>   plaintext secrets out of source code, deployment managers, containers,
>   and metadata, and make these accessible to users as well as service
>   accounts via decryption using the Cloud KMS API.

Comment: How to use these secrets in the yaml config for a Google App Engine standard enivronent?

Comment: I've actually been using Google Secret Manager instead. I have a script that is a wrapper to `gcloud app deploy` and it fetches the secrets, creates a new temp app.yaml and injects the secrets in there