# Who can read files with secrets on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

If i deploy a config with secrets to Google App Engine, who can exactly read this config?

For instance, i have a config.json, which holds API secrets, which i don't want to let anyone see. Who could potentially see this file?

The reason for this question is, if it's worth using some key encryption services for the config file.

Comment: Google launched a secrets management tool recently: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/secrets-management  You may want to switch to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As clarified in the documentation [Predefined App Engine roles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/roles#predefined_roles), the below roles are the ones that can visualize the configs from App Engine:

- App Engine Admin
- App Engine Service Admin
- App Engine Deployer
- App Engine Viewer
- App Engine Code Viewer

Outside of the users with one of the above roles, **no one should have access to your config files**, which includes your `config.json` with your secrets.

Since this is a security matter, I think adding encryption is always a good idea. This way, you will add an additional layer of security to your application - something that is always good.

In case you decide to go with encryption, I would recommend you to check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423252/12767257), where some encryptions and options of how to do it are described and that I believe would help you.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: thanks gabriel, but from the web, nobody can see the files, which are hosted server-side, correct?

Comment: Hi @David exactly. Nobody should have access to it, since it's stored in the server-side. As long as it's not updated to a more "public" place, like a repository, for example, it should not be a problem. :)

Comment: It would be better to use secret manager for API keys that won't change that often. Then you can limit access even further with IAM roles. https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/quickstart