# How to pass the env secret variable in google app engine and gitlab CI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-deployment

I am using gitlab and deploying it to google app engine for my nodejs application.

Google Service access is added as variable in gitlab settings

```json
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY: 
   {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "node-us",
      "private_key_id": "",
      "private_key": "",
      "client_email": "gitlab-demo-service-account@node-us.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "",
      "auth_uri": "",
      "token_uri": "",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
      "client_x509_cert_url": ""
    }
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```yaml
image: node:latest
cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    
before_script:
  - echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-jessie main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
  - curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get -qq -y install google-cloud-sdk

deploy_production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - echo $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
    - gcloud --quiet --project node-us app deploy app.yaml

after_script:
  - rm /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.json
```

my root folder has `app.yaml` file and `.env` file

As of now I was testing the flow which worked fine and deployed successfully to google app engine. (it does not contain any secret keys)

However I want the my env variables (containing secret keys) need to be ignored in `.gitignore` also not to be part of `app.yaml` file.

How can I pass my env secret keys?

Comment: It's not clear for me what is VC. Can you explain? In addition, I don't understand your blocking point. What do you want to add, and what do you want to ignore? at which time? Why? If you have an example, it will be perfect!! Thanks

Comment: Ok.. VC -> version controlled, though removed as it may be creating confusion.  How can I pass the env variable secret key values. It will work if I add it in the root folder however that cannot be done as it contain secrets, how can I pass the env variables to google app engine. At which point : That is what I also need to know?

Comment: I thought to use https://medium.com/@brian.young.pro/how-to-add-environmental-variables-to-google-app-engine-node-js-using-cloud-build-5ce31ee63d7 however there is not repo connect for google cloud build trigger with gitlab

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass it!

Use [Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) to pass your secret. So, in your repository, use the secret manager URI to reference the secret, with the secret version. Like this, no secret in your code or in the app.yaml/.env files.

If you need to update the secret, do it manually. Some tasks are hard, or expensive, to automate.

*Note: The article that you mention has been released 6 months before Secret Manager release (early this year 2020)*

Answer (score 1):

If you need to send your env file to your hosted website in Google Cloud (Engine/Run) you can simply add this line in your .gitlab-ci.yml file, after the deploy script:

```
- echo $ENV > .env
```

Then, in your Gitlab config, you add the ENV variable with your .env data.

This worked for me.

This is my example Gitlab YML file that I use to deploy a NodeJS server into Google Cloud Run:

```yaml
variables:
  SERVICE_NAME: 'server'

image: google/cloud-sdk:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get --assume-yes install npm
  - npm install
  - npm run build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - main
  script:
    - echo $GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT > gcloud-service-key.json
    - echo $ENV > .env
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file gcloud-service-key.json
    - gcloud auth configure-docker
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud config set run/region europe-west3
    - gcloud run deploy $SERVICE_NAME --source . --allow-unauthenticated
```