# Environment Variables Google Cloud / App Engine Java Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy my Spring Boot application to Google cloud, but I am having trouble running it because my database configuration uses environment variables.

Here is my DB config:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
                .url(getDataSourceUrl())
                .username(System.getenv("DB_USERNAME"))
                .password(System.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
                .build();
    }

    private String getDataSourceUrl() {
        return "jdbc:postgresql://"
                + System.getenv("DB_HOST") + "/"
                + System.getenv("DB_NAME")
                + "?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false";
    }
}
```

This was setup with Heroku in mind and it works there but I can't figure out how to tell google that there are Env Variables to look for and how to define them.
I read about Functions with google cloud and created one, but it didn't seem to do the trick.

Anyone know how I should be setting this up?

EDIT 1:
I have added the variable to Google Secret Manager with their values, however I am still getting a PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

full log:

```
2021-04-27 16:39:44 default[20210427t113752]  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.        
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]      
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]                                            
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]    
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]              
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]    
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]            
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]   
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]                     
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]     
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]        
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]      
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]         
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                                  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                                  at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                                     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) ~[spring-jdbc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]    
at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]       
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]        
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]        
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]                                          at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]                                                at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]                                         
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]                                     
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]                                 
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.2.jar!/:2.4.2]                                          
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:an]       
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:an]      
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:an]    
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:an]                     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                       
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                       
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                     
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                      
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                 
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                        
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                          
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]                                                                 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]                                           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]      at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]          at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]                                                         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]                                                                                   at com.HowlingWolfe.HowlingWolfe.HowlingWolfeApplication.main(HowlingWolfeApplication.java:11) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]                     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[HowlingWolfe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[HowlingWolfe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                            at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[HowlingWolfe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]                                                                                             at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[HowlingWolfe-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]  Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: null                                         at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:220) ~[na:na]         at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:na]                          at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]   at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]                                               at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]      at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.19.jar!/:42.2.19]                                                            ... 58 common frames omitted
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to store these variables the recommended tool is *Secret Manager*, especially since there are some sensitive info like your database username and password.

I think you can find the information you need in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60242257/15062605).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I followed the instructions in that link and added my variables to Google Secret Manager, but it is still not connecting to my db and failing to deploy.