# Google Cloud Secrets Manager denies access to App Engine application but works with Google Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to connect to get a secret from google's secrets manager, and the same code works for Cloud Functions, but not for App Engine.

const { SecretManagerServiceClient } = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');

```
const secretManagerServiceClient = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
const name = 'projects/000000000000/secrets/database/versions/latest';

exports.testSecretManager = async (req, res) => {
  const [version] = await secretManagerServiceClient.accessSecretVersion({ name });
  const payload = version.payload.data.toString();
  console.debug(`Payload: ${payload}`);
  res.sendStatus(200);
};
```

The same code works fine when I deploy it as a function.

[image]

But when I run the same code as a part of App Engine application. It fails with this error:

```
Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Failed to retrieve auth metadata with error: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 500
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:180:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:365:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:182:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

I believe both Cloud Functions and App Engine are managed by the same service account “App Engine default service account”. And it has rights.

It seems like `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is missing from the environment.

`console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS);` gives me undefined. Can this be a reason? How do I pass this environment to app engine then?

How can I deeper debug this?

Comment: The is no GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env vars on Google Cloud environment, you have metadata servers. App Engine is a quite old environment and sometime has strange behavior. Can you share your app.yaml file, the service account that you use and the App Engine generation (2nd I guess but let us know)?

Comment: Please find [a response here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423252/16313960).

The [official Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/using-other-products) doesn't list GAE as a directly supported product, however, GCE/GKE are supported out of the box, if that's an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `Secret Manager Secret Accessor` role is granted to the Service Account from IAM for the App Engine. The exact role you would need to add is: roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor. You may refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control) for more details.

Also, have a look at this [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58371905/how-to-handle-secrets-in-google-app-engine).

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

The Google Cloud [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/accessing-the-api#oauth-scopes) notes:

> To use Secret Manager with workloads running on App Engine, you must grant any required permissions to the App Engine service.

I can verify that it worked correctly in my case (although I did have to specify the correct app ID in my secret request, and enable the Secret Accessor role for the service account in the [IAM console](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam).)